# Python 2.7 and Tkinter/tkk: Notebook tabs text top-aligned

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, tkinter, tabs

For some reason the font in my tkk notebook tab is top-aligned when running the code. I'm on macOS 10.11.6, using python 2.7. This is what it looks like:

[image: Tab font top-aligned in ttk notebook]

It's a nuissance considering the otherwise solid native look of ttk.

Does anyone know how the theme/style could be tweaked to resolve this issue, or any other fix entirely?

Here is my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

win = tk.Tk()
frame = ttk.Frame()
win.title("Python GUI")


tabControl = ttk.Notebook(win)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(tab1, text='Tab 1')
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(tab2, text="Tab2")

ttk.Label(tab1, text="Hello, this is a tab").grid(column=0, row=0)
ttk.Label(tab2, text="Hello, this is another tab").grid(column=0, row=0)

tabControl.pack(expand=0, fill="both")

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to say as I am unable to recreate the error you are experiencing. I think the best option would be to create a custom theme and then to change the layout options for your tabs

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

win = tk.Tk()
frame = ttk.Frame()
style = ttk.Style()



style.theme_create("custom_tabs", parent="alt", settings={
    "TNotebook.Tab": {
        "configure": {"padding": [10, 10, 10, 10]}
        }})

style.theme_use("custom_tabs")
win.title("Python GUI")



tabControl = ttk.Notebook(win)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(tab1, text='Tab 1')
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tabControl.add(tab2, text="Tab2")

ttk.Label(tab1, text="Hello, this is a tab").grid(column=0, row=0)
ttk.Label(tab2, text="Hello, this is another tab").grid(column=0, row=0)

tabControl.pack(expand=0, fill="both")

win.mainloop()
```

Simply change the padding as you need it, the values are as follows: 
[left padding, top padding, right padding, bottom padding]

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Marc. So you're saying you couldn't reproduce the error running on the same OS using the same theme?

Comment: Sorry about being unclear but no, I ran the code using windows. Maybe someone using MacOS will come along and have a better answer, but I wanted to give you something to go on for the mean time. It's still a strange issue though as one would imagine that tkinter would not act so differently across OSs.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. It seems to be fine on Windows. In fact it my experience watching videos and reading articles is that Tkinter looks better on windows generally. Anyway... Your solution helped, but I think it may make the modified TNotebook.Tab look weird on other systems.