# Top-aligned Tkinter labels on macos

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI application in Tkinter on macos (Python 2.7). I followed a tutorial to create the outline but the text in the tab buttons is top-aligned, even though nothing in that direction is specified. How can I have it centered [without using a custom theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115607/python-2-7-and-tkinter-tkk-notebook-tabs-text-top-aligned)

[image]
Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

main = Tk()
main.title('Mie Solver')
main.geometry("640x320")

rows = 20
columns=2
main.rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)
main.columnconfigure(columns, weight=1)

nb = ttk.Notebook(main)
nb.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=20, rowspan=20, sticky='NESW')
nb.enable_traversal()

model_tab = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(model_tab, text='Model')

solver_tab = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(solver_tab, text='Solver')

cs_tab = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(cs_tab, text='Cross Section')

results_tab = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(results_tab, text='Results')

# Model Tab:
ttk.Label(model_tab, text="Geometry").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
Radiobutton(model_tab, text="Solid Sphere").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
ttk.Radiobutton(model_tab, text="Core-Shell").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
ttk.Radiobutton(model_tab, text="Cylinder").grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
ttk.Separator(model_tab, orient=HORIZONTAL).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=EW)

main.attributes("-topmost", True)
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you against a custom theme?

Comment: @BryanOakley Because I would like that the interface looks native on different platforms, if possible. As far as I understand, if I make a custom style, the look is basically fixed, right?

Comment: You can first name the OS you are on and then apply the customer style if need be. I believe you can use `import os` then `print(os.name)` to check what OS you are on. Combine this with a list of OS names that you need to have a costume style on and you should be able to take care of the problem. You can also use `platform.system()` from the platform library.

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to be related to Python 2.7 and the Tcl/Tk version you are using. The tab labels are centered correctly when testing your code in Python 3.7 with Tcl/Tk 8.6.9 on macOS HightSierra.

Anyway, your tab labels issue problem in python 2.7 is due to padding, you can fix it by editing the `padding` style property of your notebook. In the same time you can also fix the labels text color for selected and disabled state to match the original macOS theme:

```
...
style = ttk.Style() # create a style instance

# configure the notebook tabs padding
style.configure("TNotebook.Tab", padding=[8, 8, 8, 0])

# configure the label text color for the selected and disabled state
style.map("TNotebook.Tab", foreground=[("selected", 'white'), ("disabled", "grey")])
...
```

Here is the result :
[image: screenshot]